# Passing html string as a model property to Controller action method in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using Rich text editor in the view and want to send this html formatted text to my aspnet core 3.1 controller action method.

```
Model class:
  public class MyModel
    {
       string Description {get;set;}
       ... other properties...
    }
 Controller:
[HttpPost]
 public async Task<bool> Add(MyModel model)
{
    // model.Description is coming as null as it contains html formatted 
    //string from the Rich text editor.
}
```

How can I get the Description as string containing Html to my action method?

Comment: I think you  need to provide some addional elements what's the type of your client application (WPF, Html, angular) and please post an example  for the client so we can provide you with a solution

Answer (score 0):

Foremost, you should check the rich text editor's API for how to retrieve the html part of the editor. Then use JavaScript to attach the html your got from the editor to your desired field. I must mention, some editors allow you do that on the fly without any JavaScript. Or did you forget to do this?

```
public class MyModel
{
   [DataType(DataType.Html)]
   string Description {get;set;}
   //... other properties...
}
```

Comment: Formula12's tip helped me to look into the rich text editor and after updating the name attribute of textarea element to "Description" (same as the model property name) in my asp.net mvc view, it resolved the issue and the model is poplated with the rich text html.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the name attribute of textarea element to "Description" (same as the model property name) in my asp.net mvc view, it resolved the issue and the model is poplated with the rich text html.